# Need data from DB instead of resource ID

Tags: php, mysql

I've been using stackoverflow.com for awhile to answer questions but this is my first time posting. Thanks in advance!

I'm trying to get the actual number that is associated with this query:

```
$purchasenumber = mysql_query("SELECT `purchase_order_number` FROM `purchaseorder` ORDER BY `purchase_order_number` DESC LIMIT 1");
echo $purchasenumber;
```

I receive a "resource id #" as opposed to the actual number.

I then want to use that number retrieved to pull more data from the database. I'm essentially creating a printable page with information from two tables in the database.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM purchaseorder, customers WHERE purchase_order_number = $purchasenumber AND purchaseorder.customer_ID = customers.customer_ID");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {}
```

Anybody have any idea to convert the resource id into the actual data? I may be going about this the wrong way, if I am, let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: looking at the return value for a SELECT in [mysql_query](http://us2.php.net/mysql_query) is a resource.

Comment: You have the answer in your question. You `fetch` from the resource.

Comment: Downvoting new user without leaving a comment? It's not like he posted spam.

Comment: @user I see two comments above yours...?!

Comment: both comments were posted after the downvotes.

Comment: @user3 Because it takes a minute to type on a keyboard...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use mysql_fetch_array() to get your data from your mysql_query:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `purchase_order_number` FROM `purchaseorder` ORDER BY `purchase_order_number` DESC LIMIT 1");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $purchasenumber = $data['purchase_order_number'];
```

[More Info](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) can be found on PHP.net

Comment: `$purchasenumber` will still be an array though, I think you'll have to be even more detailed...

Comment: Yeah i haven't tested it in my local. There you go mate

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, kimbarcelona. Your response worked.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `purchase_order_number` FROM `purchaseorder` ORDER BY `purchase_order_number` DESC LIMIT 1");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$purchasenumber = $data['purchase_order_number'];
```

Then I just used a different variable for the next result

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM purchaseorder, customers WHERE purchase_order_number = $purchasenumber AND purchaseorder.customer_ID = customers.customer_ID");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {}
```

Thanks again for the responses!

Comment: Yes use different variable for different query or else you'll overwrite  the previous one. You're welcome mate